# Jquery does not add style on dynamic content

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically adding checkboxes to an HTML and jquery does not update style. I read about similar problems and tried to call .trigger("create") on the parent but still doesn't work. Below is the fiddle content: http://jsfiddle.net/ftraian/A4duX/1/

```
<div id="checkboxes"></div>
Enter new labels here: <textarea></textarea>
```

And the script which reads labels from the textarea and adds them to checkboxes div:

```
var index = '1';

$(document).ready(function () {
    var text = 'Predifined label';
    var cbElem = $("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" + index + "\">");
    var labelElem = $("<label for=\"" + index + "\">" + text + "</label>&nbsp;");
    $('#checkboxes').append(cbElem, labelElem);
    $('#checkboxes').buttonset();
});

$('textarea').bind("enterKey", function () {
    index++;
    var text = $('textarea').val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
    var cbElem = $("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" + index + "\">");
    cbElem.button();
    var labelElem = $("<label for=\"" + index + "\">" + text + "</label>&nbsp;");
    $('#checkboxes').append(cbElem, labelElem);
    $('#checkboxes').trigger("create");
    $('textarea').val('');
});
$('textarea').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});
```

Comment: Try using jquey .on ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hzUS6/)

Remove the line:

```
cbElem.button();
```

And add the line below, at the end of the `bind()` event:

```
$('#checkboxes').buttonset();
```

Side note: `bind()` is deprecated from jQuery 1.7 and `on` should be used (though that isn't the cause of your problem).

Comment: Thank you, it works. I also replaced bind() with on()